# Why can't a input tag be type submit?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to do:

```
<input type="submit" runat="server" ... />
```

Error:

```
The base class includes the field 'btnEdit', but its type (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputImage) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputSubmit).
```

**Submit is a valid type, what is wrong here?**

Comment: Not an asp developer, but wouldn't running an input button at the server submit the form, before it's ever been sent to the client?

Comment: @Marc B: In case of ASP.NET the `runat="server"` just tells ASP.NET to treat this as a server control as opposed to regular markup.  ASP.NET pages are basically trees of controls (`Form` has children, those children might have children, etc).  Each control is a node, and I'm pretty sure, all the markup between "control" nodes is treated as a single text node.  That way you can walk the tree, have each node output itself as HTML and get a full HTML page out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing something else wrong, post more code.  Appears that you are casting `btnEdit` as `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputImage`.

There is nothing wrong with doing this, it will post fine:

```
 <input type="submit" runat="server" name="bla" value="bla" />
```

Comment: this should definitely be comment.

Comment: That is what the person is asking how to do.  If this needs to be a comment then the question needs to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

The error message shows you already have a control/html element with id 'btnEdit' which is of type System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputImage.

Did you inherit your webpage class from some base class and it is possible that the base class has that control already defined.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular ASP.NET and enable submit behavior:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Foo" UseSubmitBehavior="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the "btnEdit" was defined by the image button , and then change it to the submit .

So ,

1,You can change the **System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputImage** to the **System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputSubmit** at the design.cs file .

2,Just change the id name from btnEdit to anything...